# How to extract specific columns from different files and output in one file?

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I have in a directory 12 files , each file has 4 columns. The first column is a gene name and the rest 3 are count columns. All the files are in the same directory. I want to extract 1,4 columns for each files (12 files in total) and paste them in one output file, since the first column is same for every files the output file should only have one once the 1st column and the rest will be followed by 4th column of each file. The first column of each file is same. I do not want to use R here. I am a big fan of awk. So I was trying something like below but it did not work

My input files look like
Input file 1

```
ZYG11B  8267    16.5021 2743.51
ZYG11A  4396    0.28755 25.4208
ZXDA    5329    2.08348 223.281
ZWINT   1976    41.7037 1523.34
ZSCAN5B 1751    0.0375582   1.32254
ZSCAN30 4471    4.71253 407.923
ZSCAN23 3286    0.347228    22.9457
ZSCAN20 4343    3.89701 340.361
ZSCAN2  3872    3.13983 159.604
ZSCAN16-AS1 2311    1.1994  50.9903
```

Input file 2

```
ZYG11B  8267    18.2739 2994.35
ZYG11A  4396    0.227859    19.854
ZXDA    5329    2.44019 257.746
ZWINT   1976    8.80185 312.072
ZSCAN5B 1751    0   0
ZSCAN30 4471    9.13324 768.278
ZSCAN23 3286    1.03543 67.4392
ZSCAN20 4343    3.70209 318.683
ZSCAN2  3872    5.46773 307.038
ZSCAN16-AS1 2311    3.18739 133.556
```

Input file 3

```
ZYG11B  8267    20.7202 3593.85
ZYG11A  4396    0.323899    29.8735
ZXDA    5329    1.26338 141.254
ZWINT   1976    56.6215 2156.05
ZSCAN5B 1751    0.0364084   1.33754
ZSCAN30 4471    6.61786 596.161
ZSCAN23 3286    0.79125 54.5507
ZSCAN20 4343    3.9199  357.177
ZSCAN2  3872    5.89459 267.58
ZSCAN16-AS1 2311    2.43055 107.803
```

Desired output from above

```
ZYG11B  2743.51 2994.35 3593.85
    ZYG11A  25.4208 19.854  29.8735
    ZXDA    223.281 257.746 141.254
    ZWINT   1523.34 312.072 2156.05
    ZSCAN5B 1.32254 0   1.33754
    ZSCAN30 407.923 768.278 596.161
    ZSCAN23 22.9457 67.4392 54.5507
    ZSCAN20 340.361 318.683 357.177
    ZSCAN2  159.604 307.038 267.58
    ZSCAN16-AS1 50.9903 133.556 107.803
```

here as you can see above first column from each file and 4 column , since the first column of each file is same so I just want to keep it once and rest the ouptut will have 4th column of each file. I have just shown for 3 files. It should work for all the files in the directory at once since all of the files have similar naming conventions like file1_quant.genes.sf file2_quant.genes.sf , file3_quant.genes.sf

Every files has same first column but different counts in rest column. My idea is to create one output file which should have 1st column and 4th column from all the files.

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$4}' *_quant.genes.sf > genes.estreads
```

Any heads up?

Comment: What's the desired output given that input?

Comment: @Sobrique I have modified the query

Comment: Do you have any ordering constraints on filenames or the output? (e.g. should the files be done in alphabetical order, or is any order ok? And should the resultant values be sorted numerically?)

Comment: Why do you tag your question with [r] if you don't want to use it?

Comment: ah sorry that was a mistake but now I see the tag is removed, thanks

Comment: I actually have created quite a nice script for doing just this, with a slick interface. https://github.com/hepcat72/filetools/blob/master/columnStitch.pl  You would merge the sample files like this: `columnStitch.pl *_quant.genes.sf -c '1 4' -c 4 -c 4 > genes.estreads` (assuming the order of the files in the glob is that of the example). Also, it doesn't ensure for example that the rows are in the same order, so you have to be sure to sort each file prior. A future version will allow you to designate a linking column or columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you're looking for is one line per key, collated from multiple files.

The tool you need for this job is an associative array. I think `awk` can, but I'm not 100% sure. I'd probably tackle it in perl though:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# an associative array, or hash as perl calls it
my %data;

#iterate the input files (sort might be irrelevant here) 
foreach my $file ( sort glob("*_quant.genes.sf") ) {
    #open the file for reading. 
    open( my $input, '<', $file ) or die $!;
    #iterate line by line. 
    while (<$input>) {
        #extract the data - splitting on any whitespace. 
        my ( $key, @values ) = split; 
        #add'column 4' to the hash (of arrays)
        push( @{$data{$key}}, $values[2] );  
    }
    close($input);
}

#start output 
open( my $output, '>', 'genes.estreads' ) or die;
#sort, because hashes are explicitly unordered. 
foreach my $key ( sort keys %data ) { 
    #print they key and all the elements collected. 
    print {$output} join( "\t", $key, @{ $data{$key} } ), "\n";
}
close($output);
```

With data as specified as above, this produces:

```
ZSCAN16-AS1 50.9903 133.556 107.803
ZSCAN2  159.604 307.038 267.58
ZSCAN20 340.361 318.683 357.177
ZSCAN23 22.9457 67.4392 54.5507
ZSCAN30 407.923 768.278 596.161
ZSCAN5B 1.32254 0   1.33754
ZWINT   1523.34 312.072 2156.05
ZXDA    223.281 257.746 141.254
ZYG11A  25.4208 19.854  29.8735
ZYG11B  2743.51 2994.35 3593.85
```

Comment: Sorry if I understand correctly then I should just run this program with {perl prog.pl} , since I do not see the file argument. but when am running I get the error at line 17

Comment: Yeah, save it as `something.pl` and then it'll run - it'll look in the current directory for `*_quant_genes_sf` and process them. I could condense it into a single command line, but I honestly think this task is a bit more complex than that deserves.

Comment: am getting the error perl: `warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Not an ARRAY reference at count.pl line 17, <$input> line 1.`

Comment: Edited slightly, sorry.

Comment: just want to ask, where are you making the column 4 addition? if I want to change the code for another column, where should I change? @ Sobrique

Comment: ah ok it should be `push( @{$data{$key}}, $values[1] );` for taking 3rd column

Comment: Yes. We split the 4 columns into a key, and a 3 element `@values` - which is numbered from `0` to `2`.

Comment: one thing I would like to ask, how is the file selected? I mean which is the fashion each file is considered? any idea, whether its on size of the file or date of creation, since now am naming the column headers and found the pattern not linear as organized in the directory @Sobrique

Comment: The script above has `sort` of the `glob` and `sort` of the keys - which means in both cases it's working in alphanumeric sort order. It's not too hard to do it in a different order if so desired though.

Answer (score 1):

The following is how you do it in `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS = " "};{print $1, $4}' *|awk 'BEGIN{FS = " "};{temp = x[$1];x[$1] = temp  " "  $2;};END {for(xx in x) print xx,x[xx]}'
```

As cryptic as it looks, I am just using associative arrays.

---

Here is the solution broken down:

1. Just print the key and the value, one per line.

   `print $1, $2`
2. Store the data in an associative array, keep updating

   `temp = x[$1];x[$1] = temp  " "  $2;}`
3. Display it:

   `for(xx in x) print xx,x[xx]`

Sample run:

```
[cloudera@quickstart test]$ cat f1
A k1
B k2

[cloudera@quickstart test]$ cat f2
A k3
B k4
C k1

[cloudera@quickstart test]$ awk 'BEGIN{FS = " "};{print $1, $2}' *|awk 'BEGIN{FS = " "};{temp = x[$1];x[$1] = temp  " "  $2;};END {for(xx in x) print xx,x[xx]}'
A  k1 k3
B  k2 k4
C  k1
```

As a side note, the approach should be reminiscent of the Map Reduce paradigm.

Comment: Ah yes. Thought `awk` could do associative arrays, but wasn't entirely sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{E[$1]=E[$1] "\t" $4}END{for(K in E)print K E[K]}' *_quant.genes.sf > genes.estreads
```

Order is order of appearence when reading files (so normaly based on 1 readed file)

Comment: there should be a tab if am not wrong.. that is missing in the above command

Comment: you mean the starting tab of each lines that is in your output sample afer line 1 ?

Comment: the output is not tab separated that is what I meant to say

Answer (score 0):

If the first column is the same in all the files, you can use `paste`:

```
paste <(tabify f1 | cut -f1,4) \
      <(tabify f2 | cut -f4)   \
      <(tabify f3 | cut -f4)
```

Where `tabify` changes consecutive spaces to tabs:

```
sed 's/ \+/\t/g' "$@"
```

and f1, f2, f3 are the input files' names.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it in Perl:

```
 perl -lane '$data{$F[0]} .= " $F[3]"; END { print "$_ $data{$_}" for keys %data }' input_file_1 input_file_2 input_file_3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing it with awk. And it supports using multiple files.

```
awk 'FNR==1{f++}{a[f,FNR]=$1}{b[f,FNR]=$4}END { for(x=1;x<=FNR;x++){printf("%s ",a[1,x]);for(y=0;y<=ARGC;y++)printf("%s ",b[y,x]);print ""}}' input1.txt input2.txt input3.txt
```

That line of code, give the following output

```
ZYG11B  2743.51 2994.35 3593.85  
ZYG11A  25.4208 19.854 29.8735  
ZXDA  223.281 257.746 141.254  
ZWINT  1523.34 312.072 2156.05  
ZSCAN5B  1.32254 0 1.33754  
ZSCAN30  407.923 768.278 596.161  
ZSCAN23  22.9457 67.4392 54.5507  
ZSCAN20  340.361 318.683 357.177  
ZSCAN2  159.604 307.038 267.58  
ZSCAN16-AS1  50.9903 133.556 107.803
```